# Flutter: How to add a Neumorphic Gradient?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a Neumorphic button in Flutter with a Linear gradient however when my background color is the same as the color of my button in form of a gradient, it doesn't show up as a Neumorphic Container. I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic. Can anyone guide me as to how can I do that with an example? Here is what I am trying to re-create. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
NeumorphicButton(
   padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   style: NeumorphicStyle(
      color: Colors.transparent,
   ),
   onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
   child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [color1,color2],
         ),
      ),
      child: const Text(
         'Sign Up',
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 21),
      ),
   ),
),
```